# Perl CGI Upload Encoding

Tags: perl, utf-8, cgi

when i input a string encoded utf8 in a cgi script it converted to underscore

**example 1 :**
i uploaded a file `"تجربة.jpeg"`
i have found that file named `"__________.jpeg"`

**example 2 :** i uploaded a file `"1(1).jpeg"`
i have found that file named `"1_1_.jpeg"`

i think there is two possibilities :

1. There is a function that encode special chars like the one used in PHP : `basename`
2. There is a missing function to accept UTF8 file name encoding

So what do you think?

Comment: More likely: whatever is creating the files is "sanitizing" the names first.

Comment: I think that both of your suggestions are unlikely. I think that whatever is creating those files is running the filenames through a transformation like `s/[^a-z0-9_\.]/_/g`.

Comment: @DaveCross looks you are right, i found `s/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]/_/gs` mostly it's for security reason, is there a solution for my problem to accept most chars

Comment: Well, that regex lists all of the characters that you allow in your filenames. So it's "simply" a case of adding all the characters you want to allow to that list. You'll probably want to use a range :-)

Comment: @DaveCross already done thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a regex form that turn all chars exept a-z, A-Z, 0-9 to "_"

regex form: `s/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]/_/gs`

i just added a range of chars that i need, so final results for me is :

regex form: `s/[^a-z؀-A-Z0-9-_\.]/_/gs`

range i added is : U+0600 TO U+1EEFx
it's arabic chars range

**Ref:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode

Thanks to [@Dave-Cross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7231/dave-cross)

Comment: There is an easier way to do this, without inserting potentially non-displayable characters into the regex.  Use [:alpha:].

Answer (score 0):

To match alpha, without UTF8:

```
/a-zA-Z/
```

To match alpha, with accented characters in UTF-8 and Latin1:

```
/[:alpha:]/
```

No need to complicate it any further for the next developer.